Working with character tables
I am currently a bit stumped by an old exam question, which gives a character table and wants me to deduce properties of the group: 

What is the order of $g$?
Show that $g \notin C_G(G)$
Show there is a $h \in G$ of equal order which is not conjugate of g
Show there are two irreducible representations of $G$ with the same dimensions
Show G has an irreducible representation of degree $\geq 6$

So far I have the following:

By the second orthogonality relation I get that $|C_G(g)|=11$ and since $\langle g \rangle $ is a subgroup of it, this only leaves 11 as the possible order of $g$.
$g \in C_G(G)$ would mean that every $h \in G$ is conjugate of $g$, but the character table has $0$ entries and characters are constant on conjugacy classes. Hence, if $g \in C_G(G)$ that would mean the corresponding character $\chi$ is $0$, a contradiction to the definition of the character table requiring $\chi$ to be irreducible.

Is this correct? How would I go about showing the other questions?
I know the general process of creating a character table but this is my first time working  with it this way.
Thanks!

Your solution to part 1 is correct. Part 2... not so much. Here is how I would approach these. Let $\chi_i$ denote the character corresponding to the $i$-th row of the table.

If $g$ is central, then $|C_G(G)| \ge |g| = 11$ implies that $G$ has at least 11 conjugacy classes, hence at least 11 irreps. But the table has just 10 rows.

One such element is $h = g^{-1}$. This is because $\chi_6(g^{-1}) = \overline{\chi_6(g)} \neq \chi_6(g)$.

Necessarily $\chi_7 = \overline{\chi_6}$. In particular, $\chi_6(1) = \chi_7(1)$.

The only possible characters of degree 1 are $\chi_1$ and $\chi_9$ since those are the only ones whose value at $g$ is an $11$-th root of unity. We know that $\chi_6(1) = \chi_7(1)$ from above, so $$\sum_i \chi_i(1)\chi_i(g) = \chi_1(1) - \chi_2(1) - \chi_4(1) - \chi_5(1) - \chi_6(1) + \chi_9(1) \le \chi_1(1) + \chi_9(1) - 8.$$ By orthogonality, the sum on the left-hand side is $0$, so $\chi_1(1) + \chi_9(1) \ge 8$. Either $\chi_1$ or $\chi_9$ is the trivial character, so one of these characters has degree $\ge 7$.


